# Couldn't change Indeed url while scraping with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, text-mining

i'm new to programming!

I use R for data mining, i'm scraping Indeed and my code works good until I change the URL, it gives me this error :

```r
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [5] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

But if I wait a few minutes the code with new URL works again!!!!

Do you know what the problem is?

thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you share your code ? Without it we can't see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Provide a reproducible example with url and code you have tried